# Linq Query to create Dictionary

Tags: linq, linq-to-xml

I need simple linq Query which will create Dictionary
I have Xml which contains list of customers , who can buy some products
For every customer only one product can be given as free
Below is my sample Xml
I have crated a class that look like

```
Public Class CustomerFreeItem
{
  public string CustomerID
  public string FreeproductName
  public string ActualPrice
}

<customers>
  <customer id="1">
    <product name="book" free="false" actualPrice="10"/>
    <product name="pen" free="true" actualPrice="10"/>
    <product name="scale" free="false" actualPrice="10"/>
  </customer>
  <customer id="2">
    <product name="book" free="true" actualPrice="10"/>
    <product name="pen" free="false" actualPrice="10"/>
    <product name="scale" free="false" actualPrice="10"/>
  </customer>
  <customer id="3">
    <product name="book" free="false" actualPrice="10"/>
    <product name="pen" free="false" actualPrice="10"/>
    <product name="scale" free="true" actualPrice="10"/>
  </customer>
</customers>
```

Frome Above Xml i want a Dictionary with customer ID as key and value as FreeProduct  (CustomerFreeItem object)

Please suggest

Thanks,
Salmon.

Comment: Where is your own approach ?

Comment: Is it `vb.net` or `c#`? I assumed it is `vb` from your class declaration. Also is every customer has free product? Is there exactly one free product, or there could be more free products for one customer?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thus it's not clear what language you are using (class declaration is invalid both in C# and in VB) here is C# soulution

```
XDocument xdoc = XDocument.Load(path_to_xml_file);
var query = from c in xdoc.Descendants("customer")
            let freeProduct = c.Elements("product")
                                .Where(p => (bool)p.Attribute("free"))
                                .Single()                        
            select new CustomerFreeItem()
            {
                CustomerID = (int)c.Attribute("id"),
                FreeproductName = (string)freeProduct.Attribute("name"),
                ActualPrice = (int)freeProduct.Attribute("actualPrice")
            };

Dictionary<int, CustomerFreeItem> dictionary =  
     query.ToDictionary(x => x.CustomerID);
```

I used following class declaration:

```
public class CustomerFreeItem
{
    public int CustomerID { get; set; }
    public string FreeproductName { get; set; }
    public int ActualPrice { get; set; }
}
```

And I assumed that every customer has exactly one free product.

Answer (score 0):

Make a Dictionary with the layout and use an [XmlSerializer](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.serialization.xmlserializer.aspx) and you will see the format required. Then you can just reverse the process and your Dictionary will be filled.